# Mobile first design and printing

Tags: html, css, mobile, printing

I have a mobile first website with four CSS files :

1. Main css - @media all and (min-width: 240px)
2. Small mobile devices - @media all and (min-width: 481px)
3. Large mobile devices - @media all and (min-width: 769px)
4. Desktop - @media all and (min-width: 981px)

When I try to print something from the website in desktop, on the print preview it actually looks like the mobile version. Even in landscape there are apparently not enough pixels to load the min-width 981px. That's problem number one.

Problem number one is fixed by adding the word "device" to the min-width, but then problem two, you can't see the mobile design on desktop and I need it to be visible.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `@media print` section.

Comment: with this approach I would have to basically write the whole website again for desktop only for the purpose of the print... the website is big and it would be really time consuming to do that as I see it (also the volume of the CSS files would increase significantly). please correct me if I'm wrong, cause it's important ?

Comment: Running into this problem right now at work. Did you ever find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to just make the corect sizes and styling like mentioned you can also print different points like this:

```
@media print and
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       (min-resolution: 120dpi) {

    /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */

}



@media print {

}
```